# window.location does not get updated

Tags: javascript, html

I have a Javascript function as shown below for my HTML form. I am getting the `window.location.href` as source. Then I am removing two unwanted querystring parmaeters from that. This part works fine (as can be seen from first and second alert screenshots).

But setting the `location` with new value doesn’t work. The third alert (from window.location or even document.location) still includes the unwanted query string parameters. When I observed the POST url, it has the unwanted query string parameter.

How to get the window.location updated by removing the unwanted query string parameters (so that the POST will not have the unwanted query string parameters)?

```
function sort_table(strHead)
        {

            var source = window.location.href;
            alert("SOURCE-----"+source)

            var removed = excludeQueryString (source,"SortColumnAutoRefresh");
            removed = excludeQueryString (removed,"SortOrderAutoRefresh");

            alert("REMOVED-----"+removed);

            //location.replace(removed);
            document.location.replace(removed);

            alert("LATESTLoc-----"+window.location);
            //alert("***"+document.location);

            document.getElementById('hidSort').value=strHead;
            document.frmCountList.submit();
        }

    function excludeQueryString(url, parameter) 
    {

    var urlparts= url.split('?');   
    if (urlparts.length>=2) {

        var prefix= encodeURIComponent(parameter)+'=';
        var pars= urlparts[1].split(/[&;]/g);

        for (var i= pars.length; i-- > 0;) 
        {    
            if (pars[i].lastIndexOf(prefix, 0) !== -1) 
            {  
                pars.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }

        url= urlparts[0] + (pars.length > 0 ? '?' + pars.join('&') : "");
        return url;
    } 
    else 
    {
        return url;
    }
    }
```

Alerts

[image]

Comment: Just FYI: you remove the parameters, amend the location and THEN submit? That won't work, because once setting the location will work, you'll clear the form and POST nothing! So, if you want data to be posted, you should redirect and reset the location when you *enter* the page, not when you submit it!

Comment: When you change `window.location`, you're going to cause a redirect unless you only change parts of the URL that follow a `#` symbol. You shouldn't count on any of your code working after you start a redirect.

Comment: You really should be using window.location and not document.location. Also seems weird that you would change the url and than submit  form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments.

I commented the submit (POST) and used `location.href` for GET redirect. Now the querystrings are working as expected.

```
    function sort_table(strHead)
    {

        var source = window.location.href;
        var removed = excludeQueryString(source,"SortColumnAutoRefresh");
        removed = excludeQueryString(removed,"SortOrderAutoRefresh");
        removed = excludeQueryString(removed,"SortColumnClick");
        removed = excludeQueryString(removed,"SortOrderClick");

        var sortColumn = strHead;
        var clickOrder = getClickOrder(sortColumn);
        removed = removed + "&SortColumnClick="+sortColumn+"&SortOrderClick="+clickOrder;

        //GET - Redirect
        location.href = removed;


        //document.getElementById('hidSort').value=strHead;
        //document.frmCountList.submit();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a function I whipped up right now:

```
function redirectOnBadArgs(badargs)
{
  var i, j, newloc, args, segs, isbad, redirect;

  redirect = false;
  newloc = location.href.split("?");

  if (newloc.length === 2)
  {
      args = newloc[1].split("&");

      i = 0;
      while (i < args.length)
      {
        isbad = false;
        for (j = 0; j < badargs.length; j++)
        {
          if (args[i].indexOf(badargs[j] + "=") === 0)
          {
            isbad = true;
            break;
          }
        }

        if (isbad)
        {
          args.splice(i, 1);
          redirect = true;
          continue;
        }

        i++;
      }

      newloc[1] = args.join("&");
  }

  newloc = newloc.join("?");

  if (redirect)
  {
    // DEBUG: alert("redirecting to " + newloc);
    location.href = newloc;
  }
}
```

Pass it an array of bad arguments, like this:

```
onload = function () {
    redirectOnBadArgs([ "badarg1", "badarg2" ]);
};
```

Remember, you should redirect on page load, not on submit, or you won't POST any data!